# Recursive generic conditional type definition causes error (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, recursive-datastructures, conditional-types

Consider the following:

`export type UwrapNested<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UwrapNested<X> : T`

I get the type error (with TypeScript 3.9.4):
*Type 'UwrapNested' is not generic*

Is this due to some limitation of the type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, conditional types can't be directly recursive this way.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).  There are a number of tricks people use to circumvent this.    The only one I ever recommend is to unroll your loop of types into a list of nearly-identical types that bail out at some fixed depth, like this:

```
type UnwrapNested<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UN0<X> : T;
type UN0<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UN1<X> : T;
type UN1<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UN2<X> : T;
type UN2<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UN3<X> : T;
type UN3<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UN4<X> : T;
// ...
type UN4<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UNX<X> : T;
type UNX<T> = T; // bail out
```

You pick the "bail out" depth based on compiler performance and your expected use cases.  Yes, it's ugly, but it's straightforward and is "legal":

```
type UOkay = UnwrapNested<string[][][][]> // string
type UTooMuch = UnwrapNested<string[][][][][][][][]> // string[][]
```

---

There are other tricks mentioned that use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to defer evaluation and fool the compiler into thinking the type is not recursive, but these are brittle and have very weird side effects and are not necessarily supported.  For example

```
type UnwrapNestedIllegal<T> = {
    base: T, recurse: UnwrapNestedIllegal<T extends Iterable<infer X> ? X : never>
}[T extends Iterable<any> ? "recurse" : "base"]
```

This looks vaguely possible until you try to use it, and then you get a circularity error:

```
type Oops = UnwrapNestedIllegal<string> // any
```

Is there some way to change `UnwrapNestedIllegal` to fix that?  Probably.  Is it a good idea?  I say "no", although I might have [extreme views on the subject](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373).  In fact I'd absolutely love for there to be an official supported way to get recursive conditional types, but without a strong commitment by the language designers, I can't in good conscience recommend anyone use any of these tricks.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#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)

Comment: OK, yes I already figured out that might be the way to go, but thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving the issue, as confirmed by @jcalz:

```
type UnwrapIterable1<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? X : T
type UnwrapIterable2<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UnwrapIterable1<X> : T
type UnwrapIterable3<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UnwrapIterable2<X> : T
export type UnwrapNestedIterable<T> = T extends Iterable<infer X> ? UnwrapIterable3<X> : T
```